# Vue Router. Bind data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bind, vue-router

I am developing vue app and now I am on step when I should use vue router.
But I have a little problem with data bind into router template.

Please help me.

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Script:

```
const Foo = { template: '<div>{{foo}}</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }


const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})


const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
  router,
  data: function(){
    return {foo: "asdasdas"}
  }
})
```

`{{foo}}` bind doesn't work.

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/xgrjzsup/4430/

Answer (score 5):

From the [guide on components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props) :

> Every component instance has its own isolated scope. This means you
> cannot (and should not) directly reference parent data in a child
> component’s template. Data can be passed down to child components
> using props.

and `Foo` is a child component of your app set via the router.

One way to pass data from parent to child is to use props.

Modify your `Foo` definition to accept a `foo` property:

```js
const Foo = { 
    props: ['foo'],
    template: '<div>{{foo}}</div>' 
}
```

and bind the parent property in the template

```html
<router-view :foo="foo"></router-view>
```

An updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xgrjzsup/4431/

Comment: Thanks! One more question. Very hope for answer. 1)How I should use not simple object in this case? For example `{prop1:{prop1_1:"123", prop1_2:"321"}, prop2: "asd" ..etc}`  2) How can I integrate some ajax request Before redirect to new route. For example we click on "foo" link and before redirect we make request for get object to bind.

Comment: I red that for not simple object I can use data(). But what about get data defore route go? Can I do this without vuex?

Comment: Very helpful example! Just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your case there are two ways you can access that "foo" var.

```
{{$parent.foo}}
{{$root.foo}}
```

But consider using Vuex for sharing data in your application - https://github.com/vuejs/vuex
Or pass that foo as a parameter to the route -https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it is actually useful to know about $parent and $root. However, you should probably add that it is a hacky way to solve the problem although it indeed works.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc it does not work. you have to set the data on the template you use.

in your case:

```
const Foo = {
  template: '<div>{{foo}}</div>',
  data () {
    return {
      foo: 'magic'
    }
  }
}
```

Cheers and happy coding.